# How to tell passenger_wsgi.py to look for Django project inside another folder?

Tags: python, django, hosting, cpanel

I'm trying to host a django app on cpanel but i cant find a way to tell passenger_wsgi.py to look for the django project(main file) inside another folder

My site structure is:

```
/home/project/
   tmp/
   public/
   passenger_wsgi.py
   abdi-group/
```

passenger_wsgi.py:

```
from abdiGroup.wsgi import application
```

this works fine if i move everything inside `abdi-group/` to `/home/project/`

I tried this:

passenger_wsgi.py:

```
from abdi-group.abdiGroup.wsgi import application
```

but it can't find abdiGroup(django project name) inside  `abdi-group/`

am i missing something?

Answer (score 0):

abdiGroup is supposed to be a folder in your project directory that contains the wsgi file not abdi-group. If you're making it a subfolder add an empty `__init__.py` to any new folder so Django knows it is a package and can import from it.

Answer (score 0):

You should do like this:

```js
import mysite.wsgi
application = mysite.wsgi.application
```